# Is possible to do this with a single query: get a fixed number of items of different types, ordered

Tags: mysql, variables, sql-order-by

Let's say i have a table with a "type" and a "date" column, and i want to fetch the latest 3 items of each type, ordered by date.(Can't trust the natural table order, or insertion order).
The query doesnt need to calculate all the different values for the "type" column, that can be specified in the query.

I'm trying with variables, like this:

```
set @c=0;
set @d=0;
select *, @c:=IF(type = 1, @c+1,@c), @d:=IF(type = 2, @d+1,@d) from testtable HAVING((type=1 AND @c < 3) OR (type=2 AND @d<3)) order by testdate;
```

This is "almost" working, (it's returning one more entry for each type,which is fine), and i guess it's related to way mysql is resolving the `HAVING` clause (in fact, in some scenarios i'm finding i need to use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`).Can someone shed some light in this? Am i safe using it like this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks that using HAVING is fine...I was having problems because, in my real code, i need to use a few order-by, and the last of those is RAND() (to resolve ties), and that RAND() ordering seems to mess up with the mysql variable assignment.